# Use MacBook as a monitor and controller for iMac

Tags: keyboard, macbook-pro, imac, display

I have an iMac and I also happen to have a MacBook Air. What I need is this strange layout - I want to be able to control my iMac with my MacBook. I also want to be able to  share my iMaс screen to my MacBook's. So ideally I have a single machine - iMac responsible for all the hardware and the MacBook as just as an external display and a keyboard with a touchpad. How do you achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't really use the MacBook as display or keyboard. What you can do is control the iMac remotely via Screen Sharing. This is a builti in function in OS X since 10.5: 
[Screen Sharing](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11151).

Please note that his is not a workable solutions for anything that requires fast display refreshes as all data is send via your network.

There are several instruction out there:
http://macs.about.com/od/usingyourmac/qt/Mac-Screen-Sharing-How-To-Connect-To-Another-Macs-Desktop.htm

Comment: As far as I'm concerned this wouldn't make my MacBook behave as a second display for the iMac but simply mirror it?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [ScreenRecycler](http://www.screenrecycler.com/ScreenRecycler.html). It let's you use another computer as a second monitor, which seems like what your after.

Alternatively, if you just want to use one machine to control the other you can use [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org).